# Ember.Test - using the module in integration tests for components

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to import Ember.Test into an integration test that I have for a component in order to use the test helpers that are bundled with the module.

Is there an easy way to do that without initializing an application?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to do?